# Redirect to a specific element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect

I'm learning RoR building social network. So in my views I have a index view which is rendering a mix of all the posts from my groups. 
So now, I would like to build a link to redirect toward my original post (into his group). Redirect into the group is not really a problem, but I don't know how to redirect to my post into this group.

With a code example it will be more clear :

Index view :

```
<%= @posts.each do |p| %>
  <%= p.title %>
  Publish in <%= link_to p.group.name, group_path(p.group, ROUTE TO MY POST) %>
<% end %>
```

Show view(group):

```
<%= @group.posts.each do |post|%>
  <div id='post_iter<%=post.id%>'
    <%= p.title%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

So I would like to redirect the user toward his iteration into the group Show. 
Something like

```
<%= link_to p.group.name, group_path(p.group, #post_iter#{p.id}) %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be good :

```
<%= link_to p.group.name, group_path(p.group, anchor: "post_iter(#{p.id})") %>
```